# Creating a connection with Microsoft's JDBC driver is 3 times faster than with jTDS

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds

I googled a lot but I can't figure out the reason of this strange behaviour. I'm using microsoft sql server 2012 with windows authentication. I'm connecting like that:

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://MY-PC:1433;databaseName=database;integratedSecurity=true");
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("failed" + e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This connection is aproximately 3 times faster than when I use `jtds` driver (and also add .jar to project library and so on) `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` and appropriate connection string (`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MY-PC:1433/database;instance=SQLEXPRESS`).

Does anybody know why? I read that jtds driver is much faster than sqldbc drivers, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: How do you test that connection with one driver is faster than with the other? With a single run or do you make several connections to see the average speed? Can you provide your numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jTDS driver has a lot of improvements related to the way queries work after the connection is made. Their benchmark does not mention the initial connection speed: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/benchTest.html. They only measure operations that are executed after connection is already active.

I suspect that connection initialization code is slower than for other drivers. That's why it is worth keeping a connection pool of precreated connections to get maximum performance. In fact it's true about any driver.

Comment: The page you link to is really old so I am not so sure it is still true.

Comment: That page contains a link to the test suite which OP can still use to see if the result is true or not. In any case my point was that OP need to measure driver performance not at connection time, but at query/execute time.